# Force chrome to open url instead of search

Tags: google-chrome

When developing and opening custom urls you always have to type **http://**localurl.local/ in order for Chrome to open page and not google search.
Is there some way you can force google to first try to lookup if page actually exists? And if I already have opened url and append something to string I'm being again redirected to google search which is very frustrating.
If you're not following me see this gif:
[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq92c.gif)

Comment: `.local` is not an actual TLD. So that's why you need to force Chrome via `http://`.

Comment: Well, that doesn't solve anything for me, I'm searching for some option where I can disable this option. I believe this is just stupid behaviour, specially when you append something to alraedy opened url like in image...

Comment: Tell me, without filtering on valid TLDs, how would you go about de-muxing URLs from search queries in the omnibox?

Comment: maybe try to ping domain first? if anything responds on localurl.local open it instead of searching, that few millisecond lag is way better then this completelly stupid behaviour.